# Getting the URL to a debian .deb package

Tags: debian, ubuntu-12.04, package-management, packages

I'm trying to setup an [IronWorker](http://www.iron.io/worker) with PHP, and need to add the [Imagick PECL extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/imagick) or [debian package's](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/php5-imagick) URL to the IronWorker .worker configuration.

I've located the package for Ubuntu 12.04 on the above mentioned link, but I'm not sure how to get a direct URL to the .deb file. Can anyone help?

Typically one would install this with

sudo apt-get install php5-imagick

,but since I'm using an IronWorker, I need the link to the .deb file directly.

Comment: Notice the heading **Download php5-imagick** on the package page?  Follow the link under that heading for your architecture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/php5-imagick`

Which has the architecture list, click on the desired architecture for the package download, which will send you to the list of mirrors with direct links to the file from those mirrors.

`http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/amd64/php5-imagick/download`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the command line:

```
apt-get download --print-uris php5-imagick
```

The output is:

> 'http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php-imagick/php5-imagick_3.2.0~rc1-1_amd64.deb' php5-imagick_3.2.0~rc1-1_amd64.deb 100534 SHA256:c01825bb5190466e94e1ddae0ae6d5a54d796b89fb6ca3b0fe428e39c75c4fff

If you need just the URI for a script, you can get it by piping to `cut` and `sed`:

```
$ apt-get download --print-uris php5-imagick | cut -d' ' -f1 | sed -e 's/^.//' -e 's/.$//'
http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/p/php-imagick/php5-imagick_3.2.0~rc1-1_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use search form in http://packages.ubuntu.com/

There, you can chose ubuntu flavor (before), see and link deps and chose architecture (after), and see mirror direct links (end).

At the first step, you can search even inside packets. Such as: what packet containts iostat binary? Really usefull.